# How to safely move mailbox to another server?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, hosting, imap, thunderbird

I have a hosting for my client on a shared server (website, domain and mailboxes) and I want to change the provider and move everything to another server. Moving the website is as easy as copying the content and changing the DNS settings.

What about the mailboxes?

I don't have root access to the server, but I want to keep all the data in the mailboxes.
They are using both POP3 and IMAP.

What's the best flow in this case, regarding that:

- clients have 10 computers using Thunderbird (clients are non thech-savvy, I'll need to update the settings if any, I don't have remote access to those machines)
- they are also using webmail access (roundcube)
- we want to keep all the data and minimum downtime (preferably that clients didn't notice any change in they daily work)

Once I change the DNS to the new servers, the mailboxes will be empty. How to keep the data from old mailboxes and have not to worry about any data loss?

Answer (score 3):

Use a mailbox synchronization tool (for example [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/)) or a service (for example [migrationwiz](https://www.migrationwiz.com/)) and do a initial synchronization of all the mailboxes to the new server.

Then change the dns records over to the new box. After DNS change has propagated, do another delta-sync of all mailboxes to catch the changes that have been made to the old mailbox while the mailclients switched from the old to the new server.

Comment: One nice feature of imapsync is that it can designate a root user and move all accounts without knowing each account's password. This has made several migrations very easy.